# How to modify theme/colors used in search result of Sublime Text 3?

Tags: themes, sublimetext3

When I use Ctrl-Shift-F to find text in files in Sublime Text 3 I would like to adjust how the matched text is highlighted. How do I do that?

I don't find any entries having `search` or `find` in their name in my `.tmTheme` file...

Answer (score 0):

Try editing: `selection` and `selectionBorder` in your `.tmTheme` file.

Comment: They only apply to when I manually select some text. Not when I search for something.